# An exception can lead to the closing of a SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building the treatment of a connection and came this question in mind, but I could not find a satisfactory answer. Then I come here to ask more experienced programmers. Is there any possibility that an exception can lead to the closing of an already opened `SqlConnection`?

illustrative code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

try
{
     // some code that can throw an exception here....
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // is there any possibility of this error close the connection?
}
```

Comment: It is also possible that the connection is closed on the other side and thus throwing the exception.....

Comment: Can you explain why do you think that something could possibly close the connection?

Comment: I was just thinking if it is possible or not and make this question...

Comment: thanks, i wanted know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any possibility of an exception lead to the closing of an
>   already open SqlConnection?

Exceptions will not voluntarily close an open `SqlConnection`. In all instances, you have to take care of its resources. You can do this by explicitly calling the `Close()` method (best in a `finally` block), or wrapping it in a `using` statement (this technique is often preferred).

### Explicitly calling .Close()

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
try
{
    //some code that can throw an exception here....
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //is there any possibility of this error close the connection? no
} 
finally 
{
    //call close here - finally block will always execute
    con.Close();
}
```

### Using statement

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        //some code that can throw an exception here....
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //is there any possibility of this error close the connection? no
    } 
    //Close() is taken care of by the using statement
}
```

Also, I'd recommend putting your `Open()` call inside your `try-catch` as it can throw an exception.

**Edit:**

In case you're unsure about what the `using` statement does:

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

You can read more about it in [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)